# How to run "test mode" for a specific page flutterflow

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutterflow

I'm trying to run a "test mode" for a specific page in my flutterflow application. As I do not have all the navigation buttons linked to all the due to the app is still in development I want to test a specific page that I'm working on. However everytime when I click the "test mode" button is starts from a random page. Can you tell me how to start the "test mode" for a concrete page?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings & Integrations -> App Details -> Initial Page.
Change the entry page to the specific page you want to test.